# how to read data from mongodb in zepplin using spark?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, hortonworks-sandbox

I m working with zeppelin in hdp 2.6 I want to read collection from mongodb using spark2 interpreter

```
util.Properties.versionString
spark.version
res22: String = version 2.11.8
res23: String = 2.2.0.2.6.4.0-91
```

I m using MongoDB 3.4.14 mongo-spark-connector 2.2.2 mongo-java-driver 3.5.0 when I try this

```
val customReadConfig = ReadConfig(Map("readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred" ,"uri" -> "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test.collections"))
val df5 = spark.sparkSession.read.mongo(customReadConfig)
```

I get this error

```
     customReadConfig: com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig.Self =ReadConfig(test,collections,Some(mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test.collections),1000,DefaultMongoPartitioner,Map(),15,ReadPreferenceConfig(secondaryPreferred,None),ReadConcernConfig(None),false)
     org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 20, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD$MongoCursorIterator.<init>(MongoRDD.scala:174)
at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.compute(MongoRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
```

Comment: Looks like Scala version mismatch.

Comment: scala version is 2.11.8

Comment: Scala version for one of the dependencies you've included.

Comment: I don't thonk that scala version I worked with scala 2.11.8 with the same dependency but without zeppelin and it's work but with zeppelin give this error !

Comment: you are right the problem is with mongo-spark-connector. Thank you!